# Load all relations and their children in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a rather complex structure that contains multiple relations. If my relations are defined this way, how can I load all of them in one call?

```
Model
    (has many) ChildModels1
        Child1a
        Child1b
        ...
    (has many) ChildModels2
        Child2a
        Child2b
        ...
    (has many) ChildModels3
        Child3a
        Child3a
            Child3aa
            Child3ab
            ...
```

I'm able to do the following:

```
$entity = Entity::find($id)->load('ChildModels1', 'ChildModels2', 'ChildModels3');
```

But I'm not sure how to load all the child relations too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be achieved with Eager Loading:

```
Entity::where('id', $id)->with('relation1.subrelation1', 'relation1.subrelation2', 'relation2.subrelation1', 'relation2.subrelation2')->get();
```

> When accessing Eloquent relationships as properties, the relationship
>   data is "lazy loaded". This means the relationship data is not
>   actually loaded until you first access the property. However, Eloquent
>   can "eager load" relationships at the time you query the parent model.
>   Eager loading alleviates the N + 1 query problem.

You can read more about this in the Laravel [documentation on eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick; however, it doesn't seem to be respecting that $id variable. It finds everything.